# Websharper example SPA project - bad jquery ref?

Tags: websharper

I'm trying to get started with websharper using the example SPA project template. After manually adding fsharp.core to the refs I'm able to F5, but then I get a JS syntax error in *.head.js.  I noticed that the uri for jquery

http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js

does not work - it renders a "bad gateway" page.
I tried replacing this with a valid CDN, but the Content/*.head.js file keeps getting regenerated. How do I tell WS what CDN to use?
I just downloaded VSIX today from the WS site, but is there a chance that this version is stale?
thanks

Comment: The uri works fine for me. Problem with corporate proxy maybe?

Answer (score 1):

You can add this to your `Web.config` file to modify the JQuery script link location:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="IntelliFactory.WebSharper.JQuery.Resources.JQuery" value="yourUrl" />
</appSettings>
```

However, currently the only the root path can be redirected, WS will always look for `yourUrl/jquery-1.11.0.min.js`. It would make sense to allow setting the full url (absolute or relative), this change will probably be included in the next release of WebSharper. See https://bitbucket.org/IntelliFactory/websharper/issue/294